# iOS App installation URL

Tags: ios, url, installation

Is it possible for an iPhone to install the app from a webpage on clicking a url? I understand this is possible during the ad-hoc testing phase wherein, you can host the .ipa file and add the device IDs that you want your app to be installed on and then send a url. But I wanted to know if there was away to get some other app from the app store via a url? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link directly to the apps page on the App Store, but that's about it (on a non-jailbroken iOS device). The user will have to download the app from the App Store.

Comment: Thanks Darren. Another question, is it atleast possible to get the url from where the download happens? I want to make a rule for that url in my access point. (requirement: non-jailbroken iOSdevice only).

Comment: I doubt it, as you'd be wanting a direct link to the file.